# How to hide button with CSS class?

Tags: css

I have two filter buttons appearing on my new version of HUSKY plugin.
One button is from old WOOF filter plugin with the name "Filter" on it, the other also named FILTER. And the other from new HUSKY plugin (the new version of WOOF). I'm used old WOOF plugin and recently bought new. And although I deleted the old version, for some reason an additional button appears that does not function.

How can i hide one button with extra css class ?
With  the code below all elements remains hidden.

```css
button.button {
        visibility: hidden;
}

button.button.woof_submit_search_form_container {
       visibility: visible;
}
```

Thank you !

Comment: are you asking what CSS to write or are you asking how to modify a specific button? Where and what is the button?

Comment: One button is  from old WOOF filter pluginwith the name "Filter" on it. And the other from new HUSKY plugin (the new version of WOOF). I'm used old WOOF  plugin and recently bought new.
And although I deleted the old version, for some reason an additional button appears that does not function